# Flush Result : No Connectivity issue for FBSDKAppEvents with FB analytics SDK

Tags: facebook, sdk

I tried every possible thing, followed all the documents but still getting this error both on simulator and device.

```
due to 'PersistedEvents' - {
    "advertiser_tracking_enabled" = 1;
    "anon_id" = "XZ0EAE21D7-7730-4F3E-9993-0E5F59047A32";
    "application_tracking_enabled" = 1;
    event = "CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS";
    extinfo = "[\"i2\",\"co.homebit.ios\",\"1\",\"1.0.7\",\"10.1\",\"iPhone7,1\",\"en_IN\",\"IST\",\"AirTel\",414,736,\"3.00\",2,11,8,\"Asia\\/Kolkata\"]";
}
Events: [
  {
    "event" : {
      "_ui" : "no_ui",
      "_eventName" : "fb_mobile_activate_app",
      "_logTime" : 1493722499,
      "_session_id" : "ECFBA1AD-6C9B-42B6-ADDD-B4C996CC8169",
      "fb_mobile_launch_source" : "Unclassified"
    },
    "isImplicit" : false
  }
]
Flush Result : No Connectivity
```